# Prove that $2x^3+3x^2+x$ is always divisible by 6 if x is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Prove that $2x^3+3x^2+x$ is always divisible by $6$ if $x$ is an integer.

I started by factoring the expression:

$x(2x^2+3x+1)=x(2x+1)(x+1)$

However I wasn’t sure how to progress from here to prove that it is always divisible by 6. Any ideas?

Comment: What can you say about the factored expression when $x$ is congruent to $1,2,3,4,5$ modulo $6$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done
$$x(2x^2+3x+1)=x(2x+1)(x+1)=x(2x-2+3)(x+1)
\\=2(x-1)x(x+1)+3x(x+1)$$

Now,  among any three consecutive integers one is a multiple of 3, and among two consecutive integers one is even.

Comment: I like this answer as it uses techniques I am more familiar with.

Answer (score 4):

To be divisible by $6$, you need to prove, that it's divisible by $2$ and $3$.

The first one is easy: $x(x+1)$ is always divisible by 2, because either of consecutive natural numbers is even.

With three if $x$ or $x + 1$ is divisible by 3, then it's completed. Let's consider the third case, when neither of the former is divisible by $3$: $x \equiv 1 \pmod3$, then $2x + 1=3 \equiv 0 \pmod3$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, my knowledge of mod is fairly limited so I do not fully understand your solution (I have been meaning to look into it for a while now!). However, thanks again, I am sure once I learn more about mod, your solution will become clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use induction. Let $f(x)=2x^3+3x^2+x$. Then
$$
f(x+1)-f(x)=6 (x + 1)^2
$$
implies that $f(x)$ is a multiple of $6$ for all $x \in \mathbb Z$ because $f(0)=0$ is a multiple of $6$.

Answer (score 1):

[Newton's interpolation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton.27s_series)
gives
$$
2x^3+3x^2+x = 6 \binom{x}{1} + 18 \binom{x}{2} + 12 \binom{x}{3}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Put $\,p,q = 2,3\,$ in $\,pq\mid p(\color{#c00}{x^{\large q}\!-\!x}) + q(\color{#c00}{x^{\large p}\!-\!x}) + pq\,x\,$ by little $\rm\color{#c00}{Fermat}$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/752295/242) for another instance (the methods in the other answers also appear there).

Comment: Bill Dubuque, @lhf I must say even though my answer is highest voted, I'm intimidated by yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily prove by induction that$$6+6\times2^2+6\times3^2+\cdots+6\times n^2=2n^3+3n^2+1.$$It follows immediately from this fact that $6\mid2n^3+3n^2+1$.